# Notification of edited answers when bounty is at stake

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I recently offered a bounty on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35930731/266392), seeking a more detailed answer.  The bounty was about to expire, and there hadn't been anything new posted.  I added a comment to the one answer already there, asking for more detail.

I received notification of the answer's author adding a comment with additional information, but I didn't get a notification that he had edited his answer during the bounty grace period.  As such, the bounty expired with me thinking there wasn't any additional content added.  I just visited the question and saw his answer, but can't award him the bounty.

**So, I think it would be helpful to receive notifications about edited answers when a bounty is open (including the grace period).**

I see that I can set another bounty (but need to increase the value), and will likely go that route since I'm happy with the answer provided.

Comment: This might be a big change -- not even the question owner gets notifications of answer _edits_ -- but it does make some sense.

Comment: Not in favor of this proposal, anything that helps a questioner treat SO like a personal help-desk should not be encouraged.  Good Q+A almost always requires active participation by the questioner, that can't happen when he doesn't show up for days when an active Q or bounty is in flight.  Your active bounty question does not have any edits at all, not a good sign.  If the lack of a notification forces the questioner to check back regularly then that's a good thing.